# Where should I put hundreds of downloaded images?

Tags: java, android

I want to include in my app hundreds of images. I understood that downloading an app that weighs hundreds of MB may deter some people, so I need to offer them a chance to download the images themselves. Also - the images would come only if you pay me, so there is no need for a big app.

Two questions:

1. I know you can have in google an expansion APK. How do I upload it? I can't see any option of it in the developers console.

2. Where should I put them? In what directory or how will I mange to show them? What will be the path i.e. new File([what?]) (If they will not be shown to the user its best, so please no downloading just to the SDCard).

BTW: Getting images from assets is really slow. I need them fast.

Comment: Is there still a way to use your app without the images? If not, stop trying to lie to your users by making your app look like it's small when it's really hundreds of MB.

Comment: My app revolves around the images. And I don't want to lie - A few images would come free with the app, and all the other (hundreds) would come if you pay me.

Comment: Okay, it just sounded like you wanted it to say "1 MB" and then download 200 MB (or whatever amount of data).

Answer (score 0):

When you upload you APK on the developer console, there will be an option to also upload an APK expansion file.

The thing with the APK expansion files is that when the app is downloaded on the Play Store, if the device can download the expansion file, it's downloaded at the same time, otherwise it will download the APK only.

Google's advice is that you need to be able to download the expansion file(s) at runtime to deal with memory limitations on some devices. Google offers a library and well documented samples to help you with that.

To test that your APK expansion file(s) works well, you can publish your app to Beta testing on the Android developer console.

You should read carefully the APK expansion file documentation by Google. I tried it myself and I can tell it's very well explained. All you need to know is there.

Here's the link to the doc : http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Where would I put my images in the expansion APK? All of them in raw or there is a way to access new dirs?
Also - can I charge the expansion, but leave the org app free?

Comment: Actually it's a single file with a certain formatted name. In my case it was a zip file. So you ca create a zip file with all your images and then name it as said by google in the documentation (with version code, package name and other things, it should be something like this : main.314159.com.example.app.obb).

Comment: Then when the file is downloaded you should unzip the file and move the extracted files into another place where you can access them (the external storage for example). It's very discouraged to unzip the files directly in the folder of the expansion file as this file can be deleted by the user. But as I told you, follow very carefully the documentation. It's quiet long but very useful.

Comment: Can't you extract the file to a location the user can't access? Can I extract the files to the 'raw' folder of my app?